# .dbo type in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, scripting

I'm new to scripting, and I have noticed "[ABC].dbo.xyz" in one of the scripts.

But I can't find the database "[ABC]". Any help if .dbo is a database or anything else.

Cheers

Comment: `ABC` is the database, `dbo` is the schema, `xyz` is the object (i.e. a `TABLE`,` VIEW`, etc) name.

Comment: @anurag, dbo is a scheam. However, as you are stating with sql, I suggest you go through tutorials explaining servers, databases, schemas, sps, tables views, the whole thing. It will be more efficient than using so as a tutorial

Comment: Be aware that scripts (e.g. stored procedures) may include references to databases that no longer exist or never existing to begin with. SQL Server allows one to create procs that reference non-existent objects due to deferred name resolution.

Comment: refresh your databases... it's there

Answer (score 0):

.dbo is schema name. [ABC].dbo.xyz it means

```
DataBase.SchemaName.Table
```